# Comet/iFrame Streaming Firefox issue

Tags: iframe, comet, firefox3.6

I am testing a comet app using the forever frame technique.  The problem I am having in Firefox is that when an update command issued from firefox (using an AJAX post updating a DB which in turn triggers a DB listener to raise an event which prints the script tags to the iframes of listening clients) if there are multiple script prints, only 1 or a few of them gets processed, never all. But I can see that they are all in the iframe.

Chrome and even IE6 do not suffer from this.

But here is the real puzzler: If the update is triggered from another browser, firefox will work, even though it is the exact same content that has been printed out into the iFrame.

So to sum up: if firefox issues the ajax query causing the update, it does not process all of the script tags.
If another browser issues the ajax query, the firefox browser will process all of the tags as it should.

Any ideas?

Hope I was clear enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue implementing our comet solution.  It apeared that firefox would only execute one script at a time.  In the end I went with two iframes, one for the long polling/server push and a second one for commands being sent to the server.

Comment: Tried that and it still does the same thing :/